# ARCore Unity: How do I Start and Stop Plane Detection on Command?

Tags: arcore

I am creating an app with ARCore, but I don't want ARCore to look for planes as soon as the app starts. Instead, I want the plane detection to begin when I hit a button in my app. It would also be great if I could stop the plane detection on command as well.

Does anyone know how I could do start and stop the ARCore plane detection on command?

I am building the app in Unity.

Thanks so much in advance!

Answer (score 0):

on `ARPlaneVisualizer.cs`, there is this code

```
    void OnEnable()
    {

        m_PlaneLayer = LayerMask.NameToLayer ("ARGameObject");
        ARInterface.planeAdded += PlaneAddedHandler;
        ARInterface.planeUpdated += PlaneUpdatedHandler;
        ARInterface.planeRemoved += PlaneRemovedHandler;
        HidePlane(true);
    }

    void OnDisable()
    {
        ARInterface.planeAdded -= PlaneAddedHandler;
        ARInterface.planeUpdated -= PlaneUpdatedHandler;
        ARInterface.planeRemoved -= PlaneRemovedHandler;
        HidePlane(false);
    }
```

you can use the `OnEnable()` code as start tracking and `OnDisable()` code to stop tracking.

Answer (score 0):

Initially create bool to restrict surface detection code and inatially make bool to true.

```
bool isSurfaceDetected = true;

if (isSurfaceDetected) {


            Session.GetTrackables<TrackedPlane> (_newPlanes, TrackableQueryFilter.New);

            // Iterate over planes found in this frame and instantiate corresponding GameObjects to visualize them.
            foreach (var curPlane in _newPlanes) {
                // Instantiate a plane visualization prefab and set it to track the new plane. The transform is set to
                // the origin with an identity rotation since the mesh for our prefab is updated in Unity World
                // coordinates.
                var planeObject = Instantiate (plane, Vector3.zero, Quaternion.identity,
                                      transform);
                planeObject.GetComponent<DetectedPlaneVisualizer> ().Initialize (curPlane);

                //              Debug.Log ("test....");

                // Apply a random color and grid rotation.
                //          planeObject.GetComponent<Renderer>().material.SetColor("_GridColor", new Color(Random.Range(0.0f, 1.0f), Random.Range(0.0f, 1.0f), Random.Range(0.0f, 1.0f)));
                //          planeObject.GetComponent<Renderer>().material.SetFloat("_UvRotation", Random.Range(0.0f, 360.0f));

                //

            }
```

Create a stop button in canvas and attatch below method

```
public void StopTrack()
    {
        // Make isSurfaceDetected to false to disable plane detection code
        isSurfaceDetected = false;
        // Tag DetectedPlaneVisualizer prefab to Plane(or anything else)
        GameObject[] anyName = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag ("Plane");
        // In DetectedPlaneVisualizer we have multiple polygons so we need to loop and diable DetectedPlaneVisualizer script attatched to that prefab.
        for (int i = 0; i < anyName.Length; i++) 
        {
            anyName[i].GetComponent<DetectedPlaneVisualizer> ().enabled = false;
        }

    }
```

Make sure that stop button method is in ARController